# Retrieve LWC data from another component

Tags: lightning-web-components

How do I reference the data of another LWC component?  For example in the component below how would I return the JSON data from `this.sectionInvLineItems`?

Component  is c-invLineItems

```js
 @track sectionInvLineItems= []; 

 async connectedCallback(){
  await this.initialize();
 }

 async initialize(){
     this.invLineItems = this.sectionInvLineItems.map( ( item, i ) => {
   
         return {
             ...item,
             initialState: ( i !== 0 )
         };
     });
     console.log( "Console InvLines", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.sectionInvLineItems )));
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first component expose method with api, for example:

```
@api
getSomeData(){
    return JSON.stringify(this.sectionInvLineItems );
}
```

Then in other component that uses this component, call the method to get the data

```
let dataFromOtherComponent = this.template.querySelector('c-my-component').getSomeData();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried your approach but its giving an error.  Do I need to retrieve the data in a different manner since its an array? Is the data still available after the initial connectedCallBack?

Comment: what/where is the error? you can use JSON.stringify to almost any structure, include array

Comment: It was on my end.  Thank you